# Widget Expanded height according to Listview content

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I'm trying to put the height of the Expanded Widget to the size of the Listview inside it, but I'm not getting it, here's the code:

With the code below, the listviews are very small and shrunk and I would like to set a size or leave the auto size for the content, I already tried to change from Expanded to Flexible with fit: flexfit.loose and it didn't work either

```
    class ProdutoPage extends GetView<ProdutosController> {
  final controller = Get.find<ProdutosController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('${Get.arguments}'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: 1.0, left: 1.0, right: 8.0, top: 1.0),
            child: Badge(
              position: BadgePosition.topEnd(top: 2, end: 2),
              badgeColor: Colors.red.shade800,
              badgeContent: Text(
                controller.itensCarrinho.length.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_rounded),
                iconSize: 40.0,
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Cores:',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Obx(
                    () => ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,                        
                        itemCount: controller.produtosCoresList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            dense: true,
                            contentPadding:
                                EdgeInsets.only(left: 3.0, right: 0.0),
                            visualDensity:
                                VisualDensity(horizontal: 0, vertical: -4),
                            title:
                                Text(controller.produtosCoresList[index].cor),
                            leading: Radio(
                              value: controller.produtosCoresList[index].cor,
                              groupValue: 'ROSA',
                              onChanged: (value) {},
                              activeColor: Colors.red.shade800,
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                ),
                Divider(
                  height: 5.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Tamanho:',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Obx(
                    () => ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: controller.produtosTamanhoList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          dense: true,
                          contentPadding:
                              EdgeInsets.only(left: 3.0, right: 0.0),
                          visualDensity:
                              VisualDensity(horizontal: 0, vertical: -4),
                          title:
                              Text(controller.produtosTamanhoList[index].tam),
                          leading: Radio(
                            value: controller.produtosTamanhoList[index].tam,
                            groupValue: 'IG',
                            onChanged: (value) {},
                            activeColor: Colors.red.shade800,
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                ),
                Divider(
                  height: 5.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Quantidade:',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0, left: 150.0, right: 150.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      isDense: true,
                      contentPadding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 8),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade800, width: 2.0),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade800, width: 2.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                ),
                Divider(
                  height: 5.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Observações Gerais:',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    minLines: 3,
                    maxLines: 5,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      isDense: true,
                      contentPadding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 8),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade800, width: 2.0),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade800, width: 2.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                ),
                Divider(
                  height: 5.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Observações Internas:',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    minLines: 3,
                    maxLines: 5,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      isDense: true,
                      contentPadding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 8),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade800, width: 2.0),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade800, width: 2.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                ),
                Divider(
                  height: 5.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Adicionar ao Carrinho'),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      minimumSize: Size(400, 60),
                      textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You column is quite complex, I suggest you to use CustomScrollView, [reference](https://medium.com/flutter-community/slivers-deep-dive-series-slivertoboxadapter-sliverlist-and-sliverfixedextentlist-80c2f1ad2f93).

In CustomScrollView:

- change your ListView widget to SliverList
- change your Padding widget to SliverPadding
- wrap your Text widget in SliverToBoxAdapter
- wrap your Divider widget in SliverToBoxAdapter

and see how it works.

Comment: I'll test this thank you